# Hibernate add new boolean column to database

Tags: database, hibernate

I'm trying to add a new bool column into one of the tables using annotations, I've tried

`@Column(name = "selected", nullable = true)`

`private boolean selected;`

and then I add the getter/setter but when I run the application I get this error:

`Exception occurred inside setter of com.ingens.warranty.model.WarrantyCase.warrantyDetail; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Exception occurred inside setter of com.ingens.warranty.model.WarrantyCase.warrantyDetail`

I'm pretty new to Hibernate, while my question might be a newbie question but it got me stuck quiet well

Thanks

Edit:

Ok I've found this error in the error stack, `Unknown column 'warrantyse14_.selected' in 'field list'`, apparently the column is not created and the sql select command is using that column which well doesn't exists, so I assume the annotation doesn't work for some reason, it just doesn't create the column after I run the application.

Comment: Probably this "a nullable database column was mapped to a primitive-type property". Check here http://www.dil.univ-mrs.fr/~massat/docs/hibernate-3.1/api/org/hibernate/PropertyAccessException.html

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I can't believe I actually missed that, so I've changed it to `@Column(name = "selected", nullable = false, columnDefinition="boolean defaule false")` but the error still occurs. When exactly the altering the table to add the new column happens? Maybe my annotation is wrong ? but anyway thanks for the fast reply.

Comment: the problem is with other field (warrantyDetail in WarrantyCase) getter and setter

Comment: Thanks rajesh, but that's the very first place I've checked, it's basically reading an object attribute of the warrantycase which I did try to debug but it went down deep into the framework before even reading the attribute which made it kinda impossible for me to track, since I'm really new to hibernate. I'll try to comment everything inside that getter to see if I can find out what exactly going on.. thanks anyways

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change
`private boolean selected;`

to
`private Boolean selected;`

I think that what happens is that Hibernate tries to set null value from the selected mapped column into the selected field which is primitive hence the exception. It wouldn't have happened if the field had been set to Object instead.

The column definition is useful in conjunction with schema update/validation (hbm2ddl), and the mapping doesn't cover the case where you define a new field by itself . In this case, you'll have to issue two statements:

"alter table ... add column selected ..."

"update ... set selected = false where selected is null"

In order to trigger automatic Hibernate updates to schema (apply for example the `@ColumnDefinition`), you will have to add the following Hibernate property: `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update` to persistence.xml provider property if you are using JPA, or as a property in hibernate.cfg.xml if using Hibernate alone

Comment: I already set the default to false so it shouldn't be any different using Boolean or boolean except the fact that Boolean takes more memory than boolean. but anyway it didn't work but thanks

Comment: I think that what happens is that Hibernate tries to set null value from the selected mapped column into the selected field which is primitive hence the exception. It wouldn't have happened if the field had been set to Object instead. Another option is to populate your selected column where it's null: "update ... set selected = false where selected is null"

Comment: yeah that's exactly what I thought when I first read your answer and honestly I did try it first before answering you, but shouldn't `columnDefinition="boolean defaule false"` set the value of selected column to false as default? thanks again for your reply.

Comment: The column definition holds for schema generation (hbm2ddl). Anyhow, the mapping doesn't cover the case where you define a new column and don't set default value using update statement. In such cases trying to "inject" null values into primitive types cause such errors

Comment: Ok now that's something I did not know and I appreciate you for that. So basically what you're saying is that it's better if I just alter the table and add the column and update it with let's say false value? (sorry if I got it wrong or something) and if I got it right, then does the mapping done with the annotation map the attribute to the field in db ? thanks again for your fast replies and help

Comment: The map, i.e. `columnDefinition="boolean defaule false"` triggers schema changes only once you set hibernate property `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` to a value other than "validate". Yes, what I'm saying is that you should update all your column null values to false (or true)

Comment: Hey Orid, thanks for your help, I managed to get it to work by altering the table and adding the column manually and the mapping worked pretty well as you explained to me, please put it as an answer so I can accept it. By the way how can I do it from the framework by the code? I mean not altering the table manually, is there any other way to do it?

Comment: @arashmoeen done. See my edited response how to trigger automatic schema update

Comment: Thanks for your help and the time you spent on my problem, appreciate it.